# How to point a hist in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have some troubles with a hist. I did a hist with the base R but now I'm trying to do the same with ggplot2. I would like to point some countries in my hist. I will put my data to make a reproducible example. Here is:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
url <- "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
web <- xml2::read_html(url)
dat <- rvest::html_table(web)[[1]]
names(dat)[1]<-"record"
dat<-dat[-c(1:8,224:231),-c(17:19)]
names(dat)<-c("record","Country","TotalCases","NewCases","TotalDeaths","NewDeaths",
"TotalRecovered","NewRecovered","ActiveCases","SeriosuCritical",
"Cases_M","Deaths_M","TotalTests","Tests_M","Population","Continent")
dat[dat==""]<-NA
dat[-c(1,2,16)]<-apply(dat[-c(1,2,16)],2,function(x)gsub(",","",x)) # cut commas
dat[-c(1,2,16)]<-apply(dat[-c(1,2,16)],2,function(x)as.numeric(gsub("+","",x))) # cut (+)
Lethality <- dat$TotalDeaths / dat$TotalCases * 100 # add lethality
dat <- cbind(dat,Lethality)
head(dat)
```

I have this hist chart and I would like to do the same with ggplot. Point those countries on the chart.

```
hist(dat$Lethality,col="green",xlab="Lehtality",main="COVID19 lethality across countries")
points(c(dat$Lethality[dat$Country=="Mexico"],dat$Lethality[dat$Country=="Qatar"], 
dat$Lethality[dat$Country=="Venezuela"], dat$Lethality[dat$Country=="Yemen"]),
c(0,0,0, 0),pch=17,col=c("red","blue","brown", "black"),cex=2)
legend("topright",c("Mexico","Qatar","Venezuela","Yemen"),fill=c("red","blue","brown","black"))
```

This is the hist with ggplot2, and I don't know how to point the countries and add the legend. Please help me with this and understand.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(Lethality,))+
  geom_histogram(color="purple", fill="violet")+ 
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "Lethality",y="Frecuency", 
       title="Estimated Lethality of Covid-19", 
       subtitle="Source:https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `ggplot2`. The key is adding `geom_point()` and enable the options for `fill`, `color` and `shape`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(dat,aes(Lethality))+
  geom_histogram(color="purple", fill="violet")+ 
  geom_point(data=subset(dat,Country %in% c("Mexico","Qatar","Venezuela","Yemen")),
             aes(x=Lethality,y=0,color=Country,
                 shape=Country,fill=Country))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','brown','black'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue','brown','black'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = rep(22,4))+
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "Lethality",y="Frecuency", 
       title="Estimated Lethality of Covid-19", 
       subtitle="Source:https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
```

Output:

[image]

If triangles are wanted:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(dat,aes(Lethality))+
  geom_histogram(color="purple", fill="violet")+ 
  geom_point(data=subset(dat,Country %in% c("Mexico","Qatar","Venezuela","Yemen")),
             aes(x=Lethality,y=0,color=Country,
                 shape=Country,fill=Country))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','brown','black'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue','brown','black'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = rep(24,4))+
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(x = "Lethality",y="Frecuency", 
       title="Estimated Lethality of Covid-19", 
       subtitle="Source:https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
```

Output:

[image]